# calculate lim function with plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say there is lim `(\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x}{x - 1} - 2\right)`
)
[image]

it is =-1.
How can i get plot with this value is indicated?
To be more clearly i want plot like this

how to get it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
my_func <- function(x) x / (x - 1) - 2

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun = my_func, aes(colour = "Function")) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = -1, colour = "Asymptote")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("Asymptote" = "blue", "Function" = "orange")) + 
    xlim(-10, 10) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to indicate  meaning of lim(-1) as red point,so that I did not decide lim  manually .x / (x - 1) - 2=-1

Comment: Hey, your code is excellent. However I have a question that how to deal with the vertical line at x=1 ? I think it doesn't exist actually.

Comment: @G-spot *"is it possible to indicate meaning of lim(-1) as red point"* Sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. The expression "lim(-1)" makes mathematically no sense. Are you asking how to numerically calculate the asymptote in R? That would be an entirely new question and is best asked in a separate post.

Comment: @DarrenTsai The function has a (trivial) singularity at x = 1, so the vertical line at x = 1 is a plotting artefact (just as in OPs original plot) as a result of connecting points with a line.

Comment: @Maurits Evers,  Are you asking how to numerically calculate the asymptote in R? yes, but  i want the result to display as red point.  You think  i have to ask new question?

Comment: @G-spot (1) The asymptote describes the behaviour of the function as `x → ±∞`; how do you expect to draw points `(-∞, -1]` and `(+∞, -1]`? This being a rhetorical question, the answer is you can't! That's why asymptotes are usually denoted by lines/curves. (2) As to how to infer the asymptotic behaviour of a function, that's more of a fundamental mathematical question rather than a coding question and is probably not a good fit for SO. Generally, you first need to establish that a function in fact has asymptotes (Hint: All *rational* functions have asymptotes). [...]

Comment: [continued] Next you can calculate the asymptote(s); any standard Highschool math/algebra textbook would show you how to do that. Alternatively, you can find many, *many* examples if you do a quick internet search, e.g. [here](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote4.htm), [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/polynomials/rational.html), and so on...